# Non-Isometric surfaces with equal curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

The two surfaces $S_1$, $S_2$ parameterised respectively by

$$\sigma_1(u,v) = (u\cos v,u\sin v, \ln u)$$
$$\sigma_2(u,v) = (u\cos v, u\sin v, v),$$

are, as I understand, not locally isometric. How can this be proven? They have the same Gaussian curvature, so that's not enough. The coefficients of the first fundamental form in each are not equal, but is that enough to conclude that they're not isometric? I've been taught that the coefficients of the first fundamental form depend on the parameterisation, so just because those of the above patches don't agree, how can we be sure that there isn't some local isometry $f$ such that $f\circ \sigma_1$ is a parameterisation of $S_2$?

Comment: Related here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/181502/examples-of-non-isometric-surfaces-having-the-same-curvature-function

Comment: It's related but it doesn't answer my question because I still don't know why these two surfaces are not locally isometric. Also I'm only taking a first course in differential geometry so things like Riemannian metrics are beyond me.

Comment: Ok, I'll try a different tact. Two surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ are related by isometry if their first  and second fundamental forms agree.  A weaker condition is that two surfaces are isometric if the First fundamental forms agree. Gauss' *Theorema Egregium* states that isometric surfaces have the same Gaussian curvature, but the converse is absolutely **not** true. If you already know how to compute the components of the first fundamental form try to satisfy yourself as to why those two surfaces above are not isometric.

Comment: I have done, and the coefficients are not the same. However, I have been taught that the coefficients of the first fundamental form depend on the parametrisation. That suggests to me that simply showing that the coefficients are not the same isn't sufficient to prove that they're not isometric. Wouldn't one have to prove that there is no pair of parametrisations of $S_1$ and $S_2$ that have the same first fundamental form coefficients?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the curvature functions are functions of $u$ and must agree at corresponding points, any reparametrization must leave $u$ as is. This means that, no matter how you alter your $v$ parameter, the first entries of the first fundamental form cannot change, and they are most definitely not equal.

Comment: Why do they have to agree, why does $u$ have to be left as it is?

Comment: Well, if you didn't have $(u,v)\in S_1$ corresponding to $(u,v')\in S_2$, would the curvatures still match up? You need $u^2=(u'){}^2$, so $u'=\pm u$. The sign change won't help you with matching up the first fundamental form. By the way, good for you for worrying about this!!

Comment: Thank god I finally get it. Thanks very much

Comment: You're most welcome. Accept at your convenience so this will go off the "unanswered" list. And keep up the good work!

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you please elaborate on why the argument "The first entries of the fundamental form cannot change" is enough? (one can choose different coordinates of course, and there is no way to choose *isometric* coordinates - since these surfaces are not flat). What I am trying to say, is that I do not see why this shows there is no local isometry. I think something is still missing... Thanks.

Comment: I'm saying (as I already did) that the fact that $K=-1/(1+u^2)^2 = -1/(1+(u')^2)^2 = K'$ will force (up to sign) $u=u'$. Do you not agree?

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you elaborate on why the first coefficients must equal? I am still not seeing it. I have calculated all the coefficients and the curvatures for each parametrization.

Comment: If $f$ is a local isometry, it carries $(u,v)$ to $(u',v')$ in such a way that the first fundamental forms (and therefore the curvatures) agree at the corresponding points. The formula for curvature tells you that you must have $u'=\pm u$. Independent of what you do with $v$, the first fundamental forms at $(u,v)$ and $(u',v') = (\pm u,v')$ cannot agree.