# How to show that these surfaces aren't locally isometric?

Tags: differential-geometry

### I have two surfaces $S$ and $S^*$ parametrized by $X(u,v)$ and $X^*(u,v)$ s.t. the first fundamental forms' coefficients are $$E(u,v)=1+\frac{1}{u^2},\quad F=0,\quad G=u^2.$$ and $$E^*=1,\quad F^* =0, \quad G^*=u^2+1.$$ How do I show that they are not locally isometric?

As both of them have the same Gaussian  Curvature, my attempt is, fix $p\in S$, and suppose that $Y$ is another parametrization of $S$ around $p$ s.t. the coefficients of the first fundamental rule associated to $Y$ are $E^*$, $F^*$ and $G^*$. Then, let $w=u'X_u+v'X_v=u'Y_u+v'Y_v$. Then,
$$E(u')^2+2Fu'v'+G(v')^2=E^*(u')^2+2F^*u'v'+G^*(v')^2$$
i.e.,
$$(1+\frac{1}{u^2})(u')^2+u^2(v')^2=(u')^2+(u^2+1)(v')^2.$$
Rearranging,
$$\frac{1}{u^2}(u')^2=(v')^2.$$
Then,
$$\frac{u'}{u}=v'.$$
Which is not true for all $w\in T_pS$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather famous example (assuming your first fundamental forms came from the two surfaces I'm thinking of). See [this posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1973957/non-isometric-surfaces-with-equal-curvature) and my answer (with comments).

(In general, you should try to search with keywords before you post!)